# Annoying Windows RDP dialog box: "you have been disconnected because another connection was made"

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop

Here is the scenario:

From my Windows 10 desktop, I connect locally to my virtual machine using RDP.

I'm working on, let's say, a spreadsheet.  All is well.

With this desktop session still open, and everything on the screen still visible, I go to my laptop and using RDP to connect to the same virtual machine.

Back on the desktop, the connection closes and I am shown the following dialog box:

"You have been disconnected because another connection was made to the remote computer."

My issue is *not* that I've been disconnected.  That's exactly what I want, and I only want one session at a time.

My issue is that everything on the desktop session is still visible behind the dialog box.

I have to physically go back to the desktop and click OK on the dialog box to truly close the session and make it disappear.

Back when Windows 8.1 was my desktop RDP host, it did not do this.

Is there a registry edit or policy edit I can make to prevent this dialog box from appearing?

In the dialog box there is not a box you can check to 'never show this again'.

Comment: Use autohotkey to watch for that window and click OK whoever it appears.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that!